# Unable to find Dynamic Xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, selenium-webdriver-c#

I am unable to find dynamic xpath for below code

```
<input class="login_button" type="submit" tabindex="3" id="@COMMAND_EVENT@" name="@COMMAND_EVENT@" value="Submit" style="top: 20px; left: 360px; width: 60px; height: 20px; position: absolute">
```

Tried:

1. `//*[contains(@tabIndex,"3") AND contains(@class="login_button")]`
2. `//input[contains(@tabIndex,"3") AND contains(@class="login_button")]`
3. `//input[@name,'@COMMAND_EVENT@'][tabIndex,'3']`

Note: tabIndex used twice for other element too

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this `contains(@class="login_button")` is a proper xpath syntax (however since you're not mentioning parse errors looks like it is) at least for your task.

**Try:**

1. `//*[contains(@tabindex,"3") and contains(@class, "login_button")]`
2. `//input[contains(@tabindex,"3") and contains(@class, "login_button")]`
3. `//input[@name='@COMMAND_EVENT@'][@tabindex='3']`

**What matters here:**

- you have `tabindex` but use `tabIndex` in your queries (it has different letter case)
- the parser that I used for test didn't accept `AND` in upper-case but worked fine with lowercase `and`

Comment: Thanks Alexey for Answer however when i tried below xpath //input[@name='@COMMAND_EVENT@'][@tabindex='3'] then also i am unable to click on submit button....not sure why ...and console shows no error


Note: //input[@name='@COMMAND_EVENT@'][@tabindex='3'] found unique value when searched in chrome inspect element.

Comment: may be it is disabled? The fact you have successfully located an element does not guarantee you will be able to interact with it.

Comment: What are the other ways to successfully click the element?
Can you please help..

Comment: I am not getting you. What do you mean? The only way to succesfully click an element is to locate it and invoke `click()` for that element. If you are not able to click using this approach that your UI likely makes the interaction not possible. There are hundred different reasons (it is hidden under other elemetns, you have not provided required data so javascript blocks the interaction, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You can try following xpath  to click on said element

```
//input[@class='login_button'][@type='submit']
```

Make sure you see only 1 found while evaluate the above xpath in browser else you need to take some surround element to make the xpath unique

Additionally, You can use `JavascriptExecutor` to perform the click.

Java code sample:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='login_button'][@type='submit']"));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 

js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Thanks Narendra for the help...i am able to click now...